# What would time.sleep(1000) do within runInteraction of Twisted's dbapi?

Tags: scrapy, twisted

I'm using Twisted's adbapi to asynchronously write items to a SQL db in the item pipeline. What happens if I insert a "time.sleep(1000)" in a `runInteraction` of the Twisted dbapi?

Does Twisted just see the code is blocking and jump to doing something else until the block stops? (i.e. I can do any blocking thing I want within runInteraction), or have I just made my code blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runInteraction` [runs in a thread](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.3.0/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool.html#runInteraction) and does not block the main reactor thread.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity why does it need to invoke a new thread? I thought the point of the async model was that if you had say 2 blocking functions, then you could just use 2 defereds  and twisted would alternate between them according to which is blocking/non-blocking and then callback each's respective callback functions (I'm only beginning with Twisted, so I'm prob misunderstanding things). I just don't get what the point of defered is if not this...

Comment: Blocking is blocking; if you `time.sleep`, that thread is not going anywhere while it sleeps. Deferred gives you a way to have return values from event-driven functions. [deferLater](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/time.html) would be the event-driven alternative to `sleep`. Similarly, a database API like [txpostgres](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txpostgres) uses non-blocking sockets instead of the blocking dbapi.